# How do I elegantly handle nil cases in my array assignment - Ruby?

Tags: ruby

So I am pushing some elements on my array like this:

```
upd_city_list << [ j.children[0].text.strip!.gsub(/\s+\W/, ''), j.children[1].text, j.children[1][:href] ]
```

The above is in an iterator (hence the use of `j`).

The issue is that from time to time, the `j.children[0].text` turns up as `nil`, and Ruby doesn't like that.

I could add a bunch of if statements before this assignment, but that seems a bit inelegant to me.

How do I handle nil cases in this situation in an elegant way?

One possible solution is, when there is a nil value, just push the string `none` onto the array....but what would that look like?

Thanks.

Edit1:

This is the error I am getting:

```
NoMethodError: private method ‘gsub’ called for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is that [`strip!`](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/String%3astrip%21) returns nil when there are no changes to the string. Your `text` method *is* returning a string, it is your `strip!` method is returning nil. I don't know why it does this. I dislike it, too.

**This case of the problem will go away if you just change `strip!` to `strip`**

In a more general sense, you might create an object to return the array for you. You don't want to go changing (what I assume is) Nokogiri, but you can wrap it in something to hide the [train wrecks](http://codevanced.net/post/The-Law-of-Demeter-The-crux-of.aspx) that result.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes total sense and you are right.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `j.children[0].text.strip!` with one of two things:

```
(j.children[0].text || 'none').strip
```

or

```
j.children[0].text.to_s.strip
```

These will, of course, have different effects when the text is nil.  I think your ACTUAL problem is that `strip!` was returning nil, and that should have been obvious to you from the error message.

Comment: So just to be clear, it would look like this, right: `j.children[0].text.to_s.strip!.gsub(/\s+\W/, '')`?

Comment: Btw, added the error message I am getting. Still getting it - even with your suggestions.

Comment: Yes it would look like that if you follow my instructions.  I suspect that `strip!` sometimes returns nil.  Try using `strip` and see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the case for one to use null object programming pattern. Nil is not a good null object. Try reading [here](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/) and [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?NullObject). Null object is the elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

`nil or a_string` will be `a_string`

so what about `(j.children[0].text or 'none')`

Comment: That's possible, but I'd use symbol :none, what if text itself turns out to be 'none'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in rails, this is a great use for the try method.

Also seems that your strip and gsub are redundent.  Please consider this implementation:

```
descriptive_name_1 = j.children[0].text.try(:strip)
descriptive_name_2 = j.children[1].text
descriptive_name_3 = j.children[1][:href]
updated_city_list << [ descriptive_name_1 , descriptive_name_2, descriptive_name_3 ]
```

w/o try

```
descriptive_name_1 = j.children[0].text.to_s.strip 
descriptive_name_2 = j.children[1].text
descriptive_name_3 = j.children[1][:href]
updated_city_list << [ descriptive_name_1 , descriptive_name_2, descriptive_name_3 ]
```

Comment: I am not using Rails, just a Ruby script. I had thought about doing something like this, but this isn't as elegant as I would have liked....however, if I can't get it uber elegant, then I will default to this. Thanks!

Comment: j.children[0].text.to_s.strip is also safe since nil.to_s evaluates to ""

Comment: if you have a preference for a one liner, you could always go back to: `upd_city_list << [ j.children[0].text.to_s.strip, j.children[1].text, j.children[1][:href] ]
`

Comment: Thanks much, you are right Chris. I don't know why someone downvoted this answer, but I upvoted you back to 0 :( I do prefer a more elegant one-liner though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the rails environment you could try `try` method: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/82d41c969897cca28bb318f7caf301d520a2fbf3/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L50